# + Sign converted to Space in iOS How to avoid it?

Tags: ios

I need to save the string in a server as input by the user.

i.e. ABCD[]{}#%^*+=

Server log = "**password":"[]{}#%^* =**" (+ sign replaced with space)

My Code

// Create Mutable Request

````
NSString *strHeaderField_ApplicationJson   = @"application/json";

NSString *strParameter   = @"userId=test@gmail.com&password=[]{}#%^*+=**";

NSData *parameterData = [strParameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                       allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlEdit cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:timeInterval];

    [request addValue:strHeaderField_ApplicationJson forHTTPHeaderField:@"Contect-Type"];
    [request addValue:strHeaderField_ApplicationJson forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:HTTPMethodPost];
    [request setHTTPBody:parameterData];```
````

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {

    [[Singleton sharedManager] hideHUD];

    if (data.length > 0) {
        NSError *error;

        NSDictionary *responceDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        if (error) {
            [[Singleton sharedManager] showAlertTitle:MsgTitleError withMessage:MsgErrorOccured onView:self];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"responceDict : %@",responceDict);
            if ([responceDict valueForKey:@"status"]) {
                BOOL status = [[responceDict valueForKey:@"status"] boolValue];
                if (status) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
                            if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MyVehicleViewController class]]) {
                                [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:true];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
                    });
                }
                else {
                    [[Singleton sharedManager] showAlertTitle:MsgTitleError withMessage:[responceDict valueForKey:@"message"] onView:self];
                }
            }
            else {
                [[Singleton sharedManager] showAlertTitle:MsgTitleError withMessage:[responceDict valueForKey:@"message"] onView:self];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        [[Singleton sharedManager] showAlertTitle:MsgTitleError withMessage:MsgConnectionErrorOccured onView:self];
    }
    [[Singleton sharedManager] hideHUD];
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: Where is the part of your code with `ABCD[]{}#%^*+=` in it?

Comment: This string will arrived in `strParameter` which is input by user.

Comment: There is no + in your `strParameter`.

Comment: Above strParameter is just for your reference, the user can set any password like123+456 like a string in the password field, So we need to store exactly string which is user inputted. Anyway, I'll update my question and add + sign in my question.

Comment: @matt I have updated my question and + sign added to password. Did you have any solution for this?

Comment: Well, everything you're doing just seems confusing to me. Your `@"application/json"` seems to imply you think you're going to be passing JSON in the body. But then you use `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, whereas JSON must be UTF8. And then when you say `[request addValue:strHeaderField_ApplicationJson forHTTPHeaderField:@"Contect-Type"];`, there is no Contect-Type header field, so this is nonsense. But the worst of it is that the body is `"userId=test@gmail.com&password=[]{}#%^*+=**"`, and that is not JSON as you have claimed it to be. So I would expect the server to declare an error.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the `+` and I do not see where your code demonstrates that the `+` is a problem. The problem seems to me to be all the stuff I just said. Your encoding is wrong, and your headers are wrong, and the body is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *password = @"34^+=-";

 NSCharacterSet *set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] "] invertedSet];
 NSString *encodedPassword = [password stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: set];
 NSData *parameterData = [encodedPassword dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion: YES];
```

Comment: What about when user input "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] " this character in password?

Comment: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] " - These all are the characters that will get converted using percent encoding. So if user enters any of these characters, your server can easily save the string.

Comment: Did you mean "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] " only these characters are converted to NSASCIIStringEncoding?

Comment: @Vivek Yes, only these characters will be converted to percentEncoding. If you want more characters you can simply add them and they will be encoded.

Comment: thank you I'll try it, Any other characters need to include? Because this field is userId and password so the user can enter any special character in the password.

Comment: @Vivek If you need to include all special characters and symbols, try this - `NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet];`